# Numerator jumping outside fraction inside tcolorbox/hbox

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox, fractions

What's going on with my fraction????

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=red!20,colframe=red!40,hbox]
\[ I = \frac{dQ}{dt} \]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

(Also, does it matter whether I put `many` or `most` when I import `tcolorbox`? What's the difference?)

Comment: Wrapping a center environment around \\[....\\] wrong. And yes, it can matter.

Comment: I know \\[…\\] is centred by default, but that wasn't the issue. I wanted to center the entire box since it was located all the way to the left, which bothered me.

Comment: Remove hbox....

Comment: Tcolorbox has keys for centering and amsmath environments, and so on. If you specify what you want to achieve, there will be ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering if you are looking for something like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{highlight math style={colback=red!20,colframe=red!40}}
\begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{equation*}
I = \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also define a box that takes the color as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{empheq}
\tcbset{enhanced,boxrule=0.8pt,bottomrule=1.6pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,lifted shadow={1mm}{-1mm}{2mm}{0.1mm}{gray!60}}
\newtcbox{\Mattbox}[1][red]{nobeforeafter,math upper,
colback=#1!20,colframe=#1!40}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box={\Mattbox}]{equation*}
I = \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box={\Mattbox[blue]}]{equation*}
I = \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, that would do the trick! However, if I wan't two boxes with different colours, is there another workaround than having to redefine `\tcbset` before every box with a new colour?

Comment: @Matt You can define your own box, please see my update.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! :-)

Comment: Hey, I thought about aligning it to the left and right and wrap some text around them using `\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{12em}...\end{wrapfigure}` environments and `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}`. It aligns to the top of the text (but only if specify 11-12ish em in the environment)… How do I get it to align totally to the lef/right (touching the outer margin)? And how can I get the text closer to the box than `12em`?

Comment: @Matt Please ask a new question for that, in which you show the precise code that has these issues. Asking questions is free, and this may help others with similar problems.